# Why is this SQL Function TicksToDateTime non-deterministic? and how to make it deterministic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, calculated-columns, sql-function

I have the following function "TicksToDateTime"

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TicksToDateTime] (@t bigint)
RETURNS datetime
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- converts the given datetime to .NET-compatible ticks
-- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cpref/html/frlrfsystemdatetimeclasstickstopic.asp
BEGIN 
    declare @result datetime
    if (@t=0)
        set @result = null
    else
        if (@t < 552877919999983334)
            set @result = cast ('1753-1-1' as datetime)
        else
            if (@t=3155378975999999999)
                set @result = cast ('9999-12-1' as datetime)
            else
                set @result = CAST((@t - 599266080000000000) / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60 AS datetime)
    return @result
END
GO
```

and the use it in a computed column of a table:

```
[CallDateRaw] BIGINT NOT NULL,
[CallDate] AS ([dbo].[TicksToDateTime]([CallDateRaw])),
```

I am now trying to index the "CallDate" column like so:

```
Create Index ExternalCalls_CallDate2 ON [External.Call] (CallDate)
GO
```

But the index fails because the column is "non-deterministic" and I can confirm that the function is also non-deterministic with:

```
select object_id('tickstodatetime')

select OBJECTPROPERTYEX(2127346643, 'IsDeterministic')
```

Which returns false..

So my question is why is this function "non-deterministic" and how do I make it deterministic? from what I read on the internet it just said add "With SchemaBinding" but as you can see I've added that and it still doesnt work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the standard SQL date constant `'17530101'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff where would I use the SQL date constant?

Comment: Using `CAST` to/from a date and time data type is not deterministic.

Comment: @Larnu thanks that gives a bit more information, so is it a case of changing all of the `Casts` to `Converts`?

Comment: I am writting a more specific answer at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `CAST` to/from the old date and time data types is not deterministic. Using `CONVERT` to/from the old date and time data types can be deterministic, for example if using a style code that is deterministic or not from a character string. You are using `CAST` here, so it isn't.

From [Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The following functions are not always deterministic, but can be used in indexed views or indexes on computed columns when they are specified in a deterministic manner.
>
> ```
> Function                   Comments
> all aggregate functions    All aggregate functions are deterministic unless they are specified with the    OVER and ORDER BY clauses. For a list of these functions, see Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL).
>
> CAST                       Deterministic unless used with datetime, smalldatetime, or sql_variant.
>
> CONVERT                    Deterministic unless one of these conditions exists:
>                            Source type is sql_variant.
>                            Target type is sql_variant and its source type is nondeterministic.
>                            Source or target type is datetime or smalldatetime, the other source or target type is a character string, and a nondeterministic style is specified. To be deterministic, the style parameter must be a constant. 
>                            Additionally, styles less than or equal to 100 are nondeterministic, except for styles 20 and 21. Styles greater than 100 are deterministic, except for styles 106, 107, 109 and 113.
> ```

In this case, you need to use `CONVERT` and a style code. So for example, instead of:

```
set @result = cast ('1753-1-1' as datetime)
```

You would need to do:

```
SET @Result = CONVERT(datetime, '17530101',112);
```

Comment: And a little more from the documentation, with examples: [Nondeterministic conversion of literal date strings into DATE values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nondeterministic-convert-date-literals)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm a bit stumped on the last line, converting ticks usng cast instead of convert. This line `CAST((@t - 599266080000000000) / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60 AS datetime)`

Comment: `bigint` to `datetime` is deterministic in `CONVERT` @user1, as the quoted documentation shows.

Comment: Yep.. I did solve it, I think its just `Convert(datetime,(@t - 599266080000000000) / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60)`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an extension to [@Larnu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62913879/2987066) excellent answer:

the function I ended up with was:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[TicksToDateTime] (@t bigint)
RETURNS datetime
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- converts the given datetime to .NET-compatible ticks
-- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cpref/html/frlrfsystemdatetimeclasstickstopic.asp
BEGIN 
    declare @result datetime
    if (@t=0)
        set @result = null
    else
        if (@t < 552877919999983334)
            set @result = Convert(datetime,'17530101',112)
        else
            if (@t=3155378975999999999)
                set @result = Convert(datetime,'99991201',112)
            else
                set @result = Convert(datetime,(@t - 599266080000000000) / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60)
    return @result
END


GO
```

and verified through

```
select object_id('TicksToDateTime')
select OBJECTPROPERTYEX(11863109, 'IsDeterministic')
```

Comment: FYI, `'9999121'` should be `'99991201'`.