# Why is my SQL function non-deterministic, when it shouldn't be?

Tags: sql-server, function, deterministic

According to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) `DATEADD` is a deterministic function hence my function below should be deterministic too:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Epoch2Date] (@i INT)
RETURNS DATETIME WITH SCHEMABINDING
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(SECOND,@i,'1970-01-01 00:00:00')
END
```

But when I check it with `SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Epoch2Date]'), 'IsDeterministic')` it returns `0` (Non-deterministic).

1. Why it is non-deterministic?
2. How can I make my function deterministic?

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913676/why-is-this-sql-function-tickstodatetime-non-deterministic-and-how-to-make-it-d) but it uses non-deterministic function `CAST` which is not the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATEADD` *is*. Implicitly converting a `varchar` to a `datetime`, however, is **not**. This is especially worse when the format you use is ambiguous for `datetime` (though at least the value would be the same).

You need to explicitly convert the value with a style:

```
DATEADD(SECOND,@i,CONVERT(datetime,'19700101',112))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's solved the issue. It would be nice to remark that on the MS docs page.

Comment: It is, @endo64 , in the document I quoted in the question you linked. An implicit cast/convert is still a cast/convert. In your attempt you have a character string value (`'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`) you are implicitly casting/converting without a style to a `datetime`; and that is **explicitly** defined as non-deterministic.

Comment: I understand, I meant, it would be nice to note that `DATEADD` makes an implicit conversion which leads to be non-deterministic.

Comment: If you feel it isn't accurate, @endo64 , then make a pull request on the document; though i personally think it does cover it (implicitly :) ).